# Making sense of Linear regression keras model plot

Tags: python

I'm using Keras boston dataset, using single feature and trying to perform a linear regression model. I have normalized the input feature. The output plot appears to be a straight line and not aligned to the data distribution:
[image: plot]
- what am I missing here? Skipped the lines to load and normalize data below.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=1,input_dim=1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=0.0001,clipvalue=0.5), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['mae','accuracy'])
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_split=0.25,batch_size=64, epochs=200,shuffle=True)
loss = model.evaluate(x_test,y_test,batch_size=None)
predict=model.predict(x_test)
plt.plot()
plt.plot(y_test, predict, 'b', x_test , y_test, 'k.')
```

Comment: Sigmoid activation gives values in 0-1 range. So you probably need to denormalize it.

Comment: This is actually denormalized data only and values do fall in that range @Jeppe

Comment: Your model trains and updates the one weight depending on how well the sigmoided-prediction fits your data. Your Y values are greater than the range of sigmoid. I don't think you need an activation at all, try 'linear'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented simple linear regression model with keras.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Train:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__lr = 0.1
        self.x_train, self.y_train, self.x_test, self.y_test, self.y_scaler = self.load_data('train.csv')
        self.train()
```

This is the part of preprocessing as following:

```
    def load_data(self, fname):
        data = np.loadtxt(fname, skiprows=1, delimiter=',')

        x_data = data[:, 1:-1]
        x_scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
        x_data = x_scaler.fit_transform(x_data)

        y_data = data[:, [-1]]
        y_scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
        y_data = y_scaler.fit_transform(y_data)

        train_size = int(len(x_data)*0.7)
        test_size = len(x_data) - train_size
        x_train, x_test = x_data[0:train_size], x_data[train_size:len(x_data)]
        y_train, y_test = y_data[0:train_size], y_data[train_size:len(y_data)]

        return x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, y_scaler
```

And, It's the training part include layers. You must use the `relu` and `mse`.
Please refer the code as following:

```
    def train(self):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(128, input_dim=len(self.x_train[0]), activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))   
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))   
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))                        
        model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['mse'])
        model.fit(self.x_train, self.y_train, epochs=5000)
        result = model.evaluate(self.x_test, self.y_test)
        predictions = model.predict(self.x_test)
        predictions = self.y_scaler.inverse_transform(predictions)
        print (predictions)

        y_test = self.y_scaler.inverse_transform(self.y_test)

        plt.plot(y_test)
        plt.plot(predictions)
        plt.show()
```

You know it's the main:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    train = Train()
```

The result is 
[image]

Comment: This is boston housing data from Keras library, and i have denormed the data. I did start with linear and later relu, but still similar graph. Tried removing clipvalue as suggested still same result.;-(

Comment: I managed to resolve the issue by fixing the learning rate to 0.01 - alternatively we can leave the lr to be defaulted by model.

Comment: Looks interesting @yahocho ..how do we decide on the number of layers and the input neurons?

Comment: @SivaDorai Yes. There is no fixed number. We can set the appropriate number of neurons to have enough weights to handle the data.  You can run my code in yourself. It's a model for boston housing data what I got from kaggle.  Try to change number of layers and neurons.

Comment: @SivaDorai Please try and let me know the result. I think it's the simplest reference sample for the linear regression what I make to be run with boston housing data for your question. Please accept this answer if it helpful for your question.